# Ruby on rails: how to post a comment without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

- I'm trying to implement a comment feature using rails 6 and jQuery, but what I want for a user can add comments to posts without refreshing the browser, I create a comment_controller.rb and the model comment.rb,
- Then I associate the post and user and comment models by has_many: comments, and belongs to user and post, but the issue is when I'm trying to create a post I found this error :

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'
Started POST "/comments" for ::1 at 2021-06-10 09:56:42 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "body"=>"good one ;)"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
   (3.8ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (15.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Rendering comments/create.js.erb
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (Duration: 294.2ms | Allocations: 1386)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7130ms (ActiveRecord: 105.2ms | Allocations: 21119)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass):
    1:
    2: $('#comment_pane').append("<%= j render @post.comments.last %>");
    3: $('#comment_body').val('');

app/views/comments/create.js.erb:2
```

- This is my **comment_controller.rb** :

  ```
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      def create  
          @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
          @comment.user_id = current_user.id if user_signed_in?
          @comment.save           
      end
      def destroy 
          @comment.destroy  
      end
      private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id, :post_id)
      end
  end
  ```
- **This is the comments lines in my index.html.erb :**

  ```
  <div id="comment_pane" class=" comment-box " >
     <%= render "comments/comments", post: post %>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom border-t pt-3 mt-3">
     <%= render  'comments/form' %>
  </div>
  ```
- **this _form.html.erb :**

  ```
  <%= form_for Comment.new, remote: true  do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

      <%= f.text_field :body, placeholder: "add comment here ..." %>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "comment-button text-blue-500 opacity-75 w-2/12 text-center font-bold", autocomplete: :off %>
  <% end %>
  ```
- **create.js.erb :**

  ```
  $('#comment_pane').append("<%= j render @post.comments.last %>");
  $('#comment_body').val('');
  ```
- The problem that I am facing is that, after a user submits a comment i found this error :

```
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass  
app/views/comments/create.js.erb:2
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because your view is expecting `@post` to exist but it was not defined. You can modify `CommentsController#create` to include the created comment's post.

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create  
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id if user_signed_in?
        @comment.save
        @post = @comment.post # or Post.find(comment_params[:post_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you very much @Rystraum , i edit my code but it doesn't work , when i use `@post = @comment.post` i found the same error , and when i use `Post.find(comment_params[:post_id])` i found another error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post without an ID):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: Hi @FazaaMajdeddine, it means you are not associating your comment to the proper post. You might have to pass the post_id somewhere so you can do so.